# how to solve the following code incorrect execution of adding customlist to gridView clickable?

Tags: android, listview, gridview

I am unable to rectify the following code problem for past 2 days. I don't know how to add custom list items to existing grid view.
I have completed and compiled this code without any errors.
but unfortunately clickable is not going to on this after clicking grid view letters.
my requirement is like this ex:if press grid view letter["A"] that should go go to another layout and should display list of items[any list/icon menu/list with icons].
so please get me out of this problem soon.
the code which I have using:

**GridViewActivity.java**

```
public class GridViewActivity extends Activity {

    GridView gridView;
    static final String[] numbers = new String[]{
            "A", "B", "C", "D", "E",
            "F", "G", "H", "I", "J",
            "K", "L", "M", "N", "O",
            "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T",
            "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"};

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.content_main);

        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, numbers);

        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                    int position, long id) {
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                       ""+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = null;
                if(position == 0){
                    intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ListActivity.class);
                   // intent.putExtra("title", list.add(list));
                }
                if(position == 1){
                    intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ListActivity.class);
                }
                if(position == 2){
                    intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ListActivity.class);
                }
                if(position == 3){
                    intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ListActivity.class);
                }
                if(position ==4){
                    intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ListActivity.class);
                }
                if(position == 5){
                    intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ListActivity.class);
                }
                if(position == 6){
                    intent = new Intent(v.get Context(), List Activity.class);}
                if(position == 7){
                    intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ListActivity.class);
                }
                if(position == 8){
                    intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ListActivity.class);
                }
                if(position == 9){
                    intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ListActivity.class);
                }
                if(position == 10){
                    intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ListActivity.class);
                }
                if(position == 11){
                    intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ListActivity.class);
                }
                if(position == 12) {
                    intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ListActivity.class);
                }
                if(position == 13){
                intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ListActivity.class);
                }
                if(position == 14){
                    intent = new Intent(v.get Context(), List Activity.class);
                }
                if(position == 15){
                    intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ListActivity.class);
                }
                if(position == 16){
                    intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ListActivity.class);
                }
                if(position == 17){
                    intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ListActivity.class);
                }
                if(position == 18){
                    intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ListActivity.class);
                }
                if(position == 19){
                    intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ListActivity.class);
                }
                if(position == 20){
                    intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ListActivity.class);
                }
                if(position == 21){
                    intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ListActivity.class);
                }
                if(position == 22){
                    intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ListActivity.class);
                }
                if(position == 23){
                    intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ListActivity.class);
                }
                if(position == 23){
                    intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ListActivity.class);
                }
                if(position == 24){
                    intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ListActivity.class);
                }
                if(position == 25){
                    intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ListActivity.class);
                }
                if(position == 26){
                    intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ListActivity.class);
                }
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

**main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:entries="@array/list"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**ListActivity.java:**

```
package com.example.brahmaiah.grid_view;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

/**
 * Created by brahmaiah on 1/29/2016.
 */
public class ListActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_grid_view, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**content_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:columnWidth="50dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
</GridView>
```

I think these content is enough to understand the problem of this app code..
the o/p coming like ...grid view has been displaying but after clicking on grid view items like {A,B...}is displaying message like this.i.e unfortunately list activity closed

Comment: can any one tell me that i.e to get get individual list item for every letter click on grid view

Answer (score 0):

First cleanup your code a little bit eliminating all those unnecessary "if" blocks. Then change the following line in your code:

```
intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ListActivity.class);
```

to

```
intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ListActivity.class);
```

**Edit:**
Additionally check that your ListActivity is in your manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".ListActivity"></activity>
```

Comment: even though nothing is happening.it was just displaying position of letters.its not taking to another layout

Comment: my requirement is to take list to another layout and should display after clicking on letters of layout

Comment: opppps..how i forget to add activity in manifest.xml..anyhow its working now..thank you so much for your kind response.

Comment: can you please tell me that how to add individual list to every letter click on gridview

Comment: I suggest to take a look to the tutorials here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html

Comment: If you have problems then you can post a separate question. And if this answer was useful don't forget to accept it. ;)